# Shell script multiple loops running at the same time

Tags: shell, loops

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the infos
Clock() {
        DATE=$(date "+%a %b %d, %T")

        echo -n " $DATE"
}

Sound() {
    Level=$(awk -F"[][]" '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master))

    echo -n " $Level"
}

# Print the info


while true
do
    echo "\c\f0 $(Clock)\ur"
    sleep 1
done &

while true
    echo "\r\f0 $(Sound)\ur"
done
```

I need to run those two loops at the same time. I googled and found that adding that "&" at the end of the first one is supposed to run it on background. However, when I tried it gave the error:

```
/home/yves/.fluxbox/bar.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/home/yves/.fluxbox/bar.sh: line 27: `done'
```

Any help is appreciated! would this be easy to just do in another language?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your second `while`-loop: you don't have a `do`, so you never close the condition-block and start the body-block.

That is — change this:

```
while true
    echo "\r\f0 $(Sound)\ur"
done
```

to this:

```
while true ; do
    echo "\r\f0 $(Sound)\ur"
done
```